# Java Generics Inferred Types

Tags: java, generics

Ok, so I am implementing the state monad in java. However, I can't seem to get the generics to work right. I have the code below, and am trying to avoid the cases indicated.

```
public interface Monad<M, A> 
{
    <B, R extends Monad<M, B>> R bind(Function<? super A, R> p_function);
}

public class State<S, A> implements Monad<State<S, ?>, A>
{
    private Function<S, Pair<S, A>> m_function;

    public State(Function<S, Pair<S, A>> p_function)
    {
        m_function = p_function;
    }

    public final Pair<S, A> run(S p_state)
    {
        return m_function.apply(p_state);
    }

    @Override
    public <B, R extends Monad<State<S, ?>, B>> R bind(
            final Function<? super A, R> p_function) 
    {
        // I want to avoid the cast to R here
        return (R) new State<S, B>((S state) -> {
            Pair<S, A> run = run(state);
            // And this cast, but they seem related
            State<S, B> applied = (State<S, B>) p_function.apply(run.second());
            return applied.run(run.first());
        });
    }
}
```

Note: I am aware that if I cange the signature of `bind` to 
 `<B> Monad<M, B> bind(Function<? super A, ? extends Monad<M, B>> p_function);`
 The cast can be avoided. However, this causes a compile error in the following method

```
public static <A, B, C, M, MB extends Monad<M, B>, MC extends Monad<M, C>> 
Function<A, MC> compose(
        Function<? super A, MB> p_first, Function<? super B, MC> p_second)
{
    // have to use an anonymous class here, because using a closure causes a
    // runtime error with the beta version of JDK 8
    return new Function<A, MC>() {

        @Override
        public MC apply(A arg) {
            MB monadOfB = p_first.apply(arg);
            return monadOfB.<C> bind(p_second); // <-- type error here
        }
    };
}
```

Now, I also tried changing the signature of `compose` in a similar manner. i.e. rather than `MB extends Monad<M, B>` I used `Monad<M, B>` where MB was used and similarly for MC. This makes the `compose` method compile. However, then the return type could not be correctly inferred by the callers of `compose` i.e.

```
Function<String, State<Integer, String>> left = ...; 
Function<String, State<Integer, String>> right = ...; 
Function<String, State<Integer, String>> composed = Monad.compose(left, right);
```

Doesn't work without specifying the types on the method call, whereas before it did.

How do I make all these generics play nicely together?

Comment: I can't seem to understand how the first one works?

Comment: The line ``msb = sb;`` assigns these types: ``Monad<State<S, ?>, B> = State<S, B>;``, that cannot work. So your comment stating "works fine" is already wrong.

Comment: @f1sh: Well, if `State extends Monad` (add generics at will) it might work.

Comment: Can you add the definitions of `State` and `Monad`?

Comment: The universe is collapsing under my roof tonight!!

Comment: Sorry yes state extends monad. I missed adding that. I'll update the post.

Comment: @ekj You should state what you exactly need and why my answer does not work for you (for some reason the whole trail of comments has been deleted...).

Comment: Can OP simplify your question by making up something that is simple and can demonstrate your problem?  There are simply too much "noise" in your code and I think no one actually get your problem clearly

Comment: I originally had the exact opposite request - to provide more detail - so I did.

Comment: @AdrianShum My attempt to simplify is below (with more edits after reading the most recent edits in OP's question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm +1'ing jacobm's answer, I just wanted to elaborate a bit on the underlying problem.)

The problem is that in Java, there is no particular relationship between `GenericClass<S>` and `GenericClass<T>`: I mean, both are subtypes of `GenericType<?>`, but there's no way that `GenericInterface<T>` can refer to the type you'd get by taking `getClass()` and substituting `T` for `S`.

In Haskell, the definition of the `Monad` typeclass looks like this:

```
class Monad m where
    (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    return :: a -> m a
```

Note that it defines `m` by using both `m a` and `m b`, meaning "the same parameterized type `m`, with (potentially) different type-arguments `a` and `b`". In Java you can't create a supertype of `m` (that is, an interface for `m`) that expresses this sort of thing, because while the supertype can refer to *itself* with arbitrary type-parameters (because it can refer to itself by name, just like how it could use any other generic type), and can refer to an arbitrary subtype with any *single* type-argument (namely its own), it has no way to refer to an arbitrary subtype with an arbitrary type-parameter. It doesn't sit "outside" the type system in the way that a Haskell typeclass definition does.

This means that there's no real way to define a generic `Monad` interface whose implementations are generic monadic types.

Comment: That's an interesting point, and one that I was aware of, but your description crytlised the concept for me. In my implementation I attempt to work around this by having the monad interface take two type parameters; M the monad type itself and A the wrapped type.

Comment: @ekj: Yes, I saw that, but the problem is that your `M` type parameter somehow needs to announce "I'm generic! give me a type argument! (and `M<A>` is special!)", and Java generics simply don't offer any way to mark a type parameter as generic, nor (therefore) to pass a type parameter *to* a type argument. You tried to work around this by using a wildcard, so e.g. `Maybe<A>` would be a `Monad<Maybe<?>, A>`, but then you ran afoul of the lack of type information encoded in that wildcard.

Comment: Hmm... Yes, it is that wild card producing the problem isn't it. It seems that I am hitting the limits of the java type system. Based on my reading, I thought I could implement monads without needing higher order kinds. Is this not the case?

Comment: @ekj: You can implement any *specific* monad, but yeah, you can't express the *concept* of monads using only the static type system. (But Java has a "runtime type" system as well. With some cleverness, and a few redundant `Class<?>` fields on various types to keep track of their type parameters, you can probably arrange things so that all of your casts actually get checked.)

Answer (score 3):

For your example to work, you need your classes to be defined similarly to:

```
class State<S, B> extends Monad<State<S, ?>, B> {}
class Monad<T, U> {}
```

`R` is a subclass of `Monad<State<S, ?>, B>`, and sb is a subclass of `Monad<State<S, ?>, B>` too, but there is no reason that it also is a `R`.

It is like writing:

```
Number n = 123.5d;
Integer i = n; //does not compile: cast required
Integer j = (Integer) n; //throws an exception
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm not familiar with what you are trying to achieve, and this simplication might not achieve your aim, but it would compile (I have removed the lambdas as I don't have a jdk8 compiler installed at the moment):

```
public class Test1 {

    public static <A, B, C, M> Function<A, Monad<M, C>> compose(final Function<? super A, Monad<M, B>> p_first, 
                                                                final Function<? super B, Monad<M, C>> p_second) {
        // have to use an anonymous class here, because using a closure causes a runtime error
        // with the beta version of JDK 8
        return new Function<A, Monad<M, C>>() {
            @Override
            public Monad<M, C> apply(A arg) {
                Monad<M, B> monadOfB = p_first.apply(arg);
                return monadOfB.bind(p_second); // <-- type error here
            }
        };
    }
}

interface Monad<M, A> {

    <B> Monad<M, B> bind(Function<? super A, Monad<M, B>> p_function);
}

class State<S, A> implements Monad<State<S, ?>, A> {

    private Function<S, Pair<S, A>> m_function;

    public State(Function<S, Pair<S, A>> p_function) {
        m_function = p_function;
    }

    public final Pair<S, A> run(S p_state) {
        return m_function.apply(p_state);
    }

    @Override
    public <B> Monad<State<S, ?>, B> bind(final Function<? super A, Monad<State<S, ?>, B>> p_function) {
        // I want to avoid the cast to R here
        return new State<S, B>(new Function<S, Pair<S, B>>() {
            public Pair<S, B> apply(S state) {
                Pair<S, A> run = run(state);
                // And this cast, but they seem related
                State<S, B> applied = (State<S, B>) p_function.apply(run.second());
                return applied.run(run.first());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the OP was not satisfied with the proposal as it removes one layer of generics.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that passes the Java 7 type checker:

```
class State<S, A> implements Monad<State<S, ?>, A> {
    private Function<S, Pair<S, A>> m_function;

    public State(Function<S, Pair<S, A>> p_function)
    {
        m_function = p_function;
    }

    public final Pair<S, A> run(S p_state)
    {
        return m_function.apply(p_state);
    }

    @Override
    public <B> Monad<State<S, ?>, B> bind(
            final Function<? super A, ? extends Monad<State<S, ?>, B>> p_function) {
        return new State<S, B>(
                new Function<S, Pair<S,B>>() {
                    public Pair<S,B> apply(S state) {
                        Pair<S, A> run = run(state);
                        // And this cast, but they seem related
                        State<S, B> applied = (State<S, B>) p_function.apply(run.second());
                        return applied.run(run.first());
                    }
        });
    }

    public static <A, B, C, M> 
    Function<A, Monad<M,C>> compose(
            final Function<? super A, ? extends Monad<M,B>> p_first, 
            final Function<? super B, ? extends Monad<M,C>> p_second) {
        return new Function<A, Monad<M,C>>() {
            @Override
            public Monad<M,C> apply(A arg) {
                Monad<M,B> monadOfB = p_first.apply(arg);
                return monadOfB.<C>bind(p_second);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The problem with your original code was that you wanted to pick a particular instantiation for `R` but your signature allowed the caller to pick it. The signature `<B, R extends Monad<State<S, ?>, B>> R bind(final Function<? super A, R> p_function)` lets the caller choose an arbitrary subtype of `Monad<State<S, ?>,B>` and demand that `bind` return it. Your `bind` implementation didn't do that, though: it decided to always return a particular subtype of `R` of your choosing. So your signature was promising one thing, but your implementation was doing another.

My fix removes that promise. Instead of allowing the caller to choose a particular `Monad<State<S,?>,B>` subtype, the revised signature just promises to return *some* subtype -- which in this case means I can dispense with the generic variable entirely and just substitute the upper bound type directly in the signature.

A similar problem affected the `compose` method -- allowing the caller to choose `MB` and `MC` types, but then expecting to be able to produce your own choice of subtypes for `MB` and `MC` in the implementation. I fixed that in a similar way.

Comment: Yes, I mention that I have tried this solution. However, it results in the type parameters having to be specified when the compose method is called. See the last code snippet in my post

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this simplification is still representative of your question:

The following compiles:

```
public class TestClass {
    public interface Monad {
        <R extends Monad> R bind();
    }

    public class State implements Monad {
        @Override
        public <R extends Monad> R bind() {
            return (R) new State(); // [1]
        }
    }

    public <M extends Monad> M apply() {
        M subMonad = null;
        return subMonad.bind();
    }
}
```

You want to remove the cast from [1].  If you do it this way:

```
public class TestClass {
    public interface Monad {
        Monad bind();
    }

    public class State implements Monad {
        @Override
        public Monad bind() {
            return new State();
        }
    }

    public <M extends Monad> M apply() {
        M subMonad = null;
        return subMonad.bind(); // [2]
    }
}
```

Then [2] doesn't compile.  Does this sum it up?  If so, can the `apply()` method simply return a `Monad`?

Comment: Yeah, I got that part... but what I really want is some pointer on how to make all my generics play nice together

Comment: That solution (return Monad from apply) is exactly what @jacobm suggested above, just in a simpler form. This poses other problems, see the last code snippet in my post.